# Print the current number of item in a cycle for x in y

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop

I have this script:

```
accounts = open("accounts.txt").readlines()

y = [x.strip().split(":") for x in accounts]

for account in y:
    print ("Trying with: %s:%s" % (account[0], account[1]))
```

the file accounts.txt is structred like this:

```
email1@email.com:test1
email2@email.com:test2
email3@gmail.com:test3
```

How can i add to the print "Trying with... bla bla" the current line of the account? An output like:

```
Trying with: email1@email.com:test1 @1
Trying with: email2@email.com:test1 @2
Trying with: email3@email.com:test1 @3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the index in Python 'for' loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), with the `start` argument as suggested by @JonClements:

```
for i, account in enumerate(y, start=1):
    print ("Trying with: %s:%s @%d" % (account[0], account[1], i))
```

You can also use unpacking to make the line more readable:

```
for i, (mail, name) in enumerate(y, start=1):
    print ("Trying with: %s:%s @%d" % (mail, name, i))
```

Finally, as @idjaw notified it, there is [a better way to format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) which is recommended over the old style:

```
for i, (mail, name) in enumerate(y, start=1):
    print("Trying with: {}:{} @{}".format(mail, name, i))
```

Comment: However, I would directly use string formatting here and just do: `"Trying with: {}:{} @{}".format(account[0], account[1], i)`

Comment: You can skip the `i + 1` as `enumerate` takes a start argument: `enumerate(y, start=1)` is somewhat more explicit to what you're using `i` for.

Comment: Also - new style string formatting wasn't introduced in Python 3 - it's been around since Python 2.6

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for position, account in enumerate(y):
    print ("Trying with: %s:%s @%d" % (account[0], account[1], position))
```